# Flash object is not working after update of google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, flash

Today google chrome updated to last version, before that update the website was working without any problem. It's working on firefox and internet explorer without any problem though.

What's wrong with google chrome ?

http://www.mersin-mezitli-satilik-daire.com/3-boyutlu-sanal-tur-mersin-mezitli-satilik-daire.php?iframe=3&anasayfa=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue may be caused by the dreaded 'Pepper' Flash Player, which has also been breaking Flash content for me in Chrome.

I don't know what the solution is for your broader audience of Chrome visitors, but to fix the problem locally:

- In a new tab, go to the URL: chrome://plugins/
- Find the entry for 'Flash' and expand [+] Details if not already expanded
- Look for the entry where the location of the plugin ends: ...PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll and click 'Disable'
- You will hopefully have at least one other instance of Flash Player installed (if not, try installing a debug player from Adobe's website), and enable one of these.

I should mention, the Pepper Flash Player seems to regularly re-enable itself, possibly whenever Chome auto-updates itself, and I find myself having to repeat this process every couple of days.

Comment: you are definitively right. it's started to work as soon as i disable the pepperflash but i can't expect from ordinary users to following those steps. there should be another solution.